# PHP form validation - error log

Tags: php

Anything wrong with this code, it works great, but I don't understand the forth line.  Why is closing bracket all by itself?  I am a fairly new to PHP and always Google for answers, but I cant figure this one out.  Hopefully, I can help others someday.  Thanks

```
<div class="errorbox">
<?php if(isset($error2)){?>
<strong class="error"><?php echo $error2;?></strong>      
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: This is normal PHP templating. It is ouputting HTML. First bracket is opening, second bracket is closing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with it. You can break in and out of PHP, and that is what this code is doing. Sometimes it's easier to break out of a PHP block to write some HTML, then go back into PHP

Answer (score 0):

It's ending the `if` statement created on line 2, but line 3 is outputting HTML so php is ended, only to begin on the next line to finish the open statement.

Answer (score 0):

Write it like this you suddenly know:

```
<div class="errorbox">
<?php 

 if(isset($error2)) {
     echo '<strong class="error">' . $error2 . '</strong>';
  }

?>
</div>
```

Or like so:

```
<div class="errorbox">
<?php 

  if(isset($error2)) {

?>
<strong class="error"><?php echo $error2;?></strong>      
<?php 

   } 

?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is normal PHP templating. It is ouputting HTML. First bracket is opening, second bracket is closing

There are several ways of doing it:

The best way is as descibed in the question:

```
<div class="errorbox">
<?php if(isset($error2)){?>
<strong class="error"><?php echo $error2;?></strong>      
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Another way is by echoing:

```
echo "<div class="errorbox">";

    <?php
     if(isset($error2)){
    echo "<strong class="error">". $error ."</strong>";
    }
    ?>      
    echo "</div>";
```